# sort by all column headings

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table which is dynamically generated upon clicking a search button as follows:

```
puts "<table class=\"resultsTable\">"
        puts "<tr><th colspan=\"10\" class=\"head\">Search Results</th></tr>"
        puts "<tr>"
        puts    "<th></th>"
        puts    "<th>App</th>"
        puts    "<th>Name</th>"
        puts    "<th>Region</th>"
        puts    "<th>Market</th>"
        puts    "<th>Language</th>"
        puts    "<th>Function</th>"
        puts    "<th>LOB</th>"
        puts    "<th>Term</th>"
        puts    "<th>Call</th>"
        puts "</tr>"
        puts "<tr>"
        puts    "<td id=\"$cellID\">"
        puts    "<img src=\"images/magnifier.gif\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" onclick=\"showRouting({'spec':'${specific}', 'id':'${mkt_id}', 'name':'${mkt_name}', 'xfer':'${xfertype}', 'cell':'${cellID}'})\"</img>"
        puts    "</td>"
        puts    "<td>$level</td>"
        puts    "<td>$name</td>"
        puts    "<td>$reg_name</td>"
        puts    "<td>$link</td>"
        puts    "<td>$lang</td>"
        puts    "<td>$func</td>"
        puts    "<td>$lob</td>"
        puts    "<td>$term</td>"
        puts    "<td>$call</td>"
        puts "</tr>"
```

Can I have some kind of sorting enabled so that I can sort by each column(By App,Name,etc.)? I have seen some sort of jquery table sorter and other things, but I am not able to do that with my code. Can someone please tell me how i would go about doing this?

what does the [0,0][1,0] mean? How would i modify my code accordingly?:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: You're gonna have to use jquery or something. Twitter Bootstrap has built in table sorting. I would suggest checking that out.

Comment: As baudday said.. There is really no way to sort tables with out using jQuery / JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://datatables.net/  or http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

For table sorter set up like this

```
// call the tablesorter plugin 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
    });
```

where sortList: `[[0,0],[2,0]]` contains column index(0 based) and sort order.

So `[[0,0],[2,0]]` means first and 3rd column will be sortable and initially they will be sorted in ascending order.

Check this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/3G5b2/) where options has been commented properly.

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/3G5b2/1/) goes a very basic version where all table columns are sortable but with no graphics e.g. arrows or backgrounds.

Comment: Do i have to download that plugin and refer to my local path or can i link to an external path? Can you also tell me what other jquery path I would need to refer?

Comment: It's better to download the js to local machine and link to them. You can link to their js for quick setup, but that not good.

Comment: Check this to see how can you setup `tablesorter` http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/3G5b2/

Comment: @ joy why is that the exact copy paste code wont work the same way in my js..http://jsfiddle.net/pveRj/

Comment: In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/3G5b2/1/ click on manage resources from left panel, you will see I added table sorter js and css there. You have to add those too. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use plug in listed here-> http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html